# Android - Popup blocking all view

Tags: android, layout, view, popup, floating-action-button

Currently, when I build a popup all the view in the activity are blocked (blacked), it's normal.

But i want to allow 1 view (FloatingActionButton) to be accessible (so not blacked). Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks for your propositions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup dialog takes all the screen as a normal behaviour and the Activity/Fragment layout behind gets unfocused... go for a Visibility trick to achieve that.

Make a layout using Relative layout and place a "dialog style" relative layout in front of everything else and set `Visibility.VISIBLE` when the user touch a button (or any other action) and `Visibility.GONE` to remove it from the view. (also, use setEnabled(false) to make sure non of the options inside that layout trigger a listener).

Anyway... all this goes against the UI/UX normal behaviour for users, I shouldn’t recommended you to go that way.

What is THAT important inside the FAB to left it available? Popup dialogs are for "YES/NO", "OK" options (mostly)

Comment: Thanks for answer,
First, when the user click on the FAB (with the '+' icon), the application start a Popup, after that, with animation, the '+' icone become 'x' and replace the cancel button. It's why I need to keep this button available

Comment: If a FAB triggers a Popup.. make the Popup OK - CANCEL (both buttons). So, when the user hits cancel, you go back to previous state. BTW, the + becoming x is when the FAB shows more options (small FAB buttons) if the FAB only opens the Popup... don't use that animation.